# Storing a struct as a blob of data breaks with some optimization passes

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm writing a compiler with LLVM as backend. Recently I turned on the optimizations, and saw my programs break in strange ways. I managed to boil things down to a minimal code, and set of optimization passes, that reproduce the problem. Here's the code:

```
define i1 @main() {
entry:
  ; Allocate space on the stack for a record
  %record = alloca { i8, i64, float }, align 8

  ; Store 1.0 in the third field of the record
  %value = getelementptr inbounds { i8, i64, float }, { i8, i64, float }* %record, i32 0, i32 2
  store float 1.000000e+00, float* %value, align 4

  ; Cast the record's location as a [3 x i64] blob, and load it
  %tmpptr = bitcast { i8, i64, float }* %record to [3 x i64]*
  %tmp = load [3 x i64], [3 x i64]* %tmpptr, align 4

  ; Store that blob on the stack
  %blob = alloca [3 x i64], align 8
  store [3 x i64] %tmp, [3 x i64]* %blob, align 4

  ; Load `value` in blob (the third field)
  %record2 = bitcast [3 x i64]* %blob to { i8, i64, float }*
  %value2ptr = getelementptr inbounds { i8, i64, float }, { i8, i64, float }* %record2, i32 0, i32 2
  %value2 = load float, float* %value2ptr, align 4

  ; Check that value is `1.0`
  %eq = fcmp oeq float %value2, 1.000000e+00

  ; Without optimization, returns 1 (true). With optimization, returns 0 (false)
  ret i1 %eq
}
```

And here are the command I run to execute it, without and with optimizations:

```bash
$ cat program.ll | opt | llc --filetype=obj -o /tmp/program.o && clang /tmp/program.o -o a.out && ./a.out
$ echo $?
1
$ cat program.ll | opt --instcombine --gvn | llc --filetype=obj -o /tmp/program.o && clang /tmp/program.o -o a.out && ./a.out
$ echo $?
0
```

Also, here's the version of LLVM I use:

```bash
$ llc --version
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 14.0.6
  Optimized build.
  Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Host CPU: tigerlake

...
```

It seems like the part that breaks is loading then storing the blob of data on the stack, then reading the value from there. If I only do two bitcasts in a row, without store/load, the problem vanishes.

Note that I left the first two fields of the record undefined for terseness, but if you do write data to them, the problem remains. Also, if you remove either the `i8` or the `i64` field, the problem disappears.

I also noticed that if I manually pad the structure as `{ i8, i8, i16, i32, i64, float, i32 }`, the problem also disappears. I don't understand why, however, because I computed the size of the array to be [3 x i64] based on the store size of the struct, which LLVM tells me is 24 bytes on my machine.

Looking a the IR generated by the optimization pass, it seems like it stores the `float` value in the 2nd `i64` location in the array, instead of the 3rd. I cannot understand why. I imagine something in this code is undefined behavior, but I have no idea what.

Comment: Haven't the time to really look at this, but in general, running the [module verifier](https://llvm.org/doxygen/Verifier_8h.html) points to almost all such problems. It leaves the solution as an exercise for the readers, though ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Unfortunately, running the module verifier yields no results :/

Comment: Shocking. Try [-print-after-all](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/1603) to see which pass does the bad change, perhaps? I'll try to have a look when I'm back from vacation on Tuesday. No promises.

Comment: Thank you. It seems like the `--instcombine` pass is causing issues, essentially by inferring that the 3rd `i64` in the array is unused, and that the `float` is in the 2nd `i64`. I don't understand why, which troubles me. For my own purposes, I managed to fix this in my compiler by replacing the `store` with a `memcpy`. I'm still however really curious to know what the problem might be, if you end up finding the time for this.